# validate all request fields with regex including arrays

Tags: regex, laravel, validation

I want to apply regex on all fields in a request to prevent forbidden characters,
normaly I would go with

```
$request->validate([
  '*' => Config::get('regex.regexStr'),
]);
```

where regexStr is the allowed charachters

the problem is when we have array value in the request it would throw an invalid field, but instead I want to validate that array items also with the same regex
how can I achieve that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
$request->validate([
   'arrayName.*' => 'regex:' . config('regex.regexStr')
]);
```

Where `arrayName` is the name of the array. There isnt not really an option to do something like `*.*`